# Printing the file content in particular order in bash

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed

I have two files. I am doing some action on `file1` which generates the another file `file2`

Here is my file1 content:

```
class parent {
   public void bye() {statement}   
   public void home1() {statement}
   public void Work() {statement}       
   public void apple() {statement}      
   public void fruits() {statement} 
  }
```

Here is my produced file2 content:

```
parent
{
        void parent.<init>() (dex_method_idx=8)  {statement}
        void parent.Work() (dex_method_idx=13) {statement}       
        void parent.apple() (dex_method_idx=9) {statement} 
        void parent.bye() (dex_method_idx=10) {statement} 
        void parent.fruits() (dex_method_idx=11) {statement} 
        void parent.home1() (dex_method_idx=12) {statement} 
}
```

The generated file2 having fixed pattern. The first function code will always be init paragraph. Then it will print the function code which starts from Capital letter (ex. Work). Then print the remaining function code by alphabetical order.

How could I print the function code of `file2` according to the order of `file1` function code.
Expected output:

```
parent
{
        void parent.<init>() (dex_method_idx=8)  {statement}    
        void parent.bye() (dex_method_idx=10) {statement} 
        void parent.home1() (dex_method_idx=12) {statement}
        void parent.Work() (dex_method_idx=13) {statement}       
        void parent.apple() (dex_method_idx=9) {statement} 
        void parent.fruits() (dex_method_idx=11) {statement}        
}
```

Please suggest me an approach.

Comment: How are you generating file2? And do you want file2 to contain the expected output, or are you looking for a command to perform on file2 to get the expected output written to your terminal?

Comment: @jvdmr,I am producing the file2 by oatdump command which always produces in fixed format. So I want some  bash command which modify the file2 to get the expected output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When I execute above code, it only display content of file1
>   It is not displaying above output

This may be due to having a pre-POSIX `awk` that doesn't know *character classes* (`[:alnum:]`, `[:space:]`). Here's a version of Ed Morton's script without character classes:

```
BEGIN { FS="[ .]+" }
NR==FNR {
    if (/^ *} *$/) inDefs=0
    if (inDefs) map[$4] = $0
    if (/^ *{ *$/) inDefs=1
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    print $2 ORS "{"
    print map["<init>()"]
    next
}
{ print $4 in map ? map[$4] : $0 }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { FS="[^[:alnum:]_]+" }
NR==FNR {
    if (/^[[:space:]]*}[[:space:]]*$/) { inDefs=0 }
    if (inDefs) { map[$4] = $0 }
    if (/^[[:space:]]*{[[:space:]]*$/) { inDefs=1 }
    next
}
FNR==1 {
    print $2 ORS "{"
    print map["init"]
    next
}
{ print ($4 in map ? map[$4] : $0) }

$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
parent
{
        void parent.<init>() (dex_method_idx=8)  {statement}
        void parent.bye() (dex_method_idx=10) {statement}
        void parent.home1() (dex_method_idx=12) {statement}
        void parent.Work() (dex_method_idx=13) {statement}
        void parent.apple() (dex_method_idx=9) {statement}
        void parent.fruits() (dex_method_idx=11) {statement}
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Can you please explain the code working?

Comment: You're welcome. It reads file2 to create a map of function name to the line you want printed, then it reads file1 and prints the contents of that map for the given function name.

Comment: When I execute above code, it only display content of file1

Comment: It is not displaying above output

Comment: Then the files you are running it against don;t look like the sample input you provided or you're not running the command in my answer or, far less likely, your awk is broken. To debug you could add `print` statements where `map` is being populated to see what it's being populated with.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know variations of your input files. This solution works with your examples.

You want the search for the functions of file1.

```
grep -o "[^ ]*()"  file1
```

The first 3 lines and the last line are special.
Combine them with

```
sed -n '1,3 p' file2
grep -f <(grep -o "[^ ]*()"  file1) file2
sed -n '$ p' file2
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way with awk :

```
awk -vl=1 '
NR==FNR {
if ($3 ~ /[(][)]$/) {
    a[$3]=++j
    }
next
}
{ split($2,e," ") }
!(e[1] in a) {
  print
  next
}
{
  d[a[e[1]]]=$0
  while ( d[l] != "" ) {
    print d[l]
    l++
    }
  }
' file1 FS=\. file2
```